# validation doesn't work if value is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code where I am saying `if website_name===""` display error however it doesn't seem to work because if I type something and delete it so it's empty it still shows it's valid so it runs else statement, however if I type a number then I get an error, but I need it to work for empty values too.

```
var message;
    var inputField = document.getElementById("website_name");
$( "#website_name" ).keyup(function() {
  if(website_name==="" || !/^[a-z]*$/.test(this.value))
  {
    $("#website_name").css('border', '3px solid red');
    inputField.style.backgroundColor = "#f27676";
    message = 'Only lower case characters allowed!';
    $('div.modal-body .msgPlaceholder').empty().append(message);
  }else{
    $("#website_name").css('border', '3px solid green');
    inputField.style.backgroundColor = "#56c145";
    message = 'Your name is correct';
    $('div.modal-body .msgPlaceholder').empty().append(message);
  }
});
```

Comment: `if(website_name=="" || !/^[a-z]*$/.test(this.value))`

Comment: The the "===" makes sure, that the data type is exactly the same as what you are comparing with. Assume website_name is undefined, then it is not true if you compare to an empty string. So use just two "==" and automatic typecasting takes place and will return a true as undefined matches an empty string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `this.value == ""` and not `website_name == ""` since `website_name` is not a `variable`

if you want to use `toLowerCase` before checking, try this:

```
var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
if (val == "")
```

```js
var message;
var inputField = document.getElementById("website_name");
$("#website_name").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value == "" || !/^[a-z]*$/.test(this.value)) {
    $("#website_name").css('border', '3px solid red');
    inputField.style.backgroundColor = "#f27676";
    message = 'Only lower case characters allowed!';
    $('div.modal-body .msgPlaceholder').empty().append(message);
  } else {
    $("#website_name").css('border', '3px solid green');
    inputField.style.backgroundColor = "#56c145";
    message = 'Your name is correct';
    $('div.modal-body .msgPlaceholder').empty().append(message);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="website_name" />
```

Comment: I'd add that to make things fair and more universal. Don't use a regex to check for uppercase/lowercase... Websites aren't limited to letter from a to z. And a better idea would be to lowercase what the user input instead of checking for lowercase... just use "toLowerCase".

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix is that a coment to me or to Przemek?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix  so how would code look like with your suggestion?

Comment: @Przemek Since LoicFaure dont seem to reply, then i updated the answer, just above the snippet i added a `toLowerCase` way for you